# How to split bytes into instructions in binary ELF file for x86

Tags: x86, c++, linux, elf, injection

I'm working on a static code injector for ELF files. I need to "steal" some bytes in order to write jump to my code on their place and then execute stolen instructions somewhere in the payload. However I don't know how to automate it. I will need to steal at least 5 bytes for my jump instruction, but obviously not always 5 bytes equal to the whole number of instructions, so I might have to `nop` several bytes.

What are the ways to distinguish instructions, given bytes in ELF binary( C/C++ preferably ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x86/x64 instruction set is variable length and there are no obvious instruction boundaries.  You can make use of a *length disassembler* to figure out how long each instruction is. There are a bunch of them available, here’s a few I found by a quick search:

https://github.com/greenbender/lend

https://github.com/Nomade040/length-disassembler

https://github.com/GiveMeZeny/fde64